# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая записывает полученные с формы html документа значения в переменные а и b, в ней на 47й строке консоль выдает ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement" независимо от того вписанно в форму что-либо или нет.

```js
let startSum = document.getElementById('start'),
    budgetValue = document.getElementsByClassName('budget-value')[0],
    dayBudjetValue = document.getElementsByClassName('daybudjet-value')[0],
    levelValue = document.getElementsByClassName('level-value')[0],
    expensesValue = document.getElementsByClassName('expenses-value')[0],
    optionalExpensesValue = document.getElementsByClassName('optionalexpenses-value')[0],
    incomeValue = document.getElementsByClassName('income-value')[0],
    monthSavingValue = document.getElementsByClassName('monthsaving-value')[0],
    yearSavingValue = document.getElementsByClassName('yearsaving-value')[0],
    expensesItem = document.getElementsByClassName('expenses-item'),
    expensesItemButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0],
    optionalItemButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1],
    countItemButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[2];

let optionalExpenses = document.querySelectorAll('.optionalexpenses-item'),
    chooseIncome = document.querySelector('.choose-income'),
    checkSaving = document.querySelector('.saving'),
    sum = document.querySelector('.choose-sum'),
    percent = document.querySelector('.choose-percent'),
    yearValue = document.querySelector('.year-value'),
    monthValue = document.querySelector('.month-value'),
    dayValue = document.querySelector('.day-value');

let time, money;

startSum.addEventListener('click', function(){
    time = prompt ("Введите наду в формате YYYY-MM-DD", '');
    money = +prompt ("Ваш бюджет на месяц?", '');

    while(isNaN(money) ||  money == "" ||  money == null) {
            money = +prompt ("Ваш бюджет на месяц?", '');
        }
    appData.budget = money;
    appData.timeData = time;
    budgetValue.textContent = money.toFixed();
    yearValue.value = new Date(Date.parse(time)).getFullYear();
    monthValue.value = new Date(Date.parse(time)).getMonth() + 1;
    dayValue.value = new Date(Date.parse(time)).getDate();
});

expensesItemButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < expensesItem.length; i++) {

        let a = expensesItem[i].value,
            b = expensesItem[++i].value;
    
        if ( (typeof(a)) != null && (typeof(b)) != null && a != '' && b != '' && a.lenght < 50) {
            console.log ("done");
            appData.expenses[a] = b;
            sum += +b;
        } else {
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
    expensesValue.textContent = sum;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
    <div class="logo">
        <span>money</span>
        keeper
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        Расчет дневного бюджета
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="data">
            <div class="choose-expenses">Введите обязательные расходы</div>
            <input class="expenses-item" type="text" id="expenses_1" placeholder="Наименование">
   <input class="expenses-item" type="text" id="expenses_2" placeholder="Цена">
   <input class="expenses-item" type="text" id="expenses_3" placeholder="Наименование">
   <input class="expenses-item" type="text" id="expenses_4" placeholder="Цена">
            <button class="expenses-item-btn">Утвердить</button>
            
            <div class="optionalexpenses">Введите необязательные расходы</div>
   <input class="optionalexpenses-item" type="text" id="optionalexpenses_1">
   <input class="optionalexpenses-item" type="text" id="optionalexpenses_2">
   <input class="optionalexpenses-item" type="text" id="optionalexpenses_3">
            <button class="optionalexpenses-btn">Утвердить</button>
            
            <div class="count-budget">Расчет дневного бюджета</div>
            <button class="count-budget-btn">Рассчитать</button>
            
            <div class="choose-income-label">Введите статьи возможного дохода через запятую</div>
            <input class="choose-income" type="text" id="income">
            
            <div class="checksavings">Есть ли накопления: 
                <input id="savings" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <label for="sum">Сумма</label>
   <input class="choose-sum" id="sum" type="text">
   <label for="percent">Процент</label>
            <input class="choose-percent" id="percent" type="text">
            
            <div class="open">
                <button class="start" id="start">Начать расчет</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="result">
            <div class="result-table">
                <div class="budget">Доход: </div>
                <div class="budget-value"></div>
    
                <div class="daybudget">Бюджет на 1 день: </div>
                <div class="daybudget-value"></div>
    
                <div class="level">Уровень дохода: </div>
                <div class="level-value"></div>
    
                <div class="expenses">Обязательные расходы: </div>
                <div class="expenses-value"></div>
    
                <div class="optionalexpenses">Возможные траты: </div>
                <div class="optionalexpenses-value"></div>
    
                <div class="income">Дополнительный доход: </div>
                <div class="income-value"></div>
    
                <div class="monthsavings">Накопления за 1 месяц:</div>
                <div class="monthsavings-value"></div>
    
                <div class="yearsavings">Накопления за 1 год:</div>
                <div class="yearsavings-value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="time-data">
                <div class="year">
                    Год:
                    <input class="year-value" type="text" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    Месяц:
                    <input class="month-value" type="text" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    День:
                    <input class="day-value" type="text" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < expensesItem.length - 1; i++) {

    let a = expensesItem[i].value,
        b = expensesItem[++i].value;

    ...

    ...  a.length < 50) {
```

---

Вот это - `(typeof(a)) != null` - что делает?

```js
var a = null;
console.log((typeof(a)) != null );
```

Comment: Проверяет чтобы "a" не было равно нулю

Comment: @VirginEvergreen Но это еще не точно?